# Using SAME Textbox to search and insert data in dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `Textbox` with which I want to be able to Search and Insert data into Table. Insert works fine with one exception: When I try to Insert data that isn't  already in DB(it's searching while I'm typing) it gives me:

> "Exception User-Unhandled System.NullReferenceException: 'Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.'
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CurrentRow.get returned null.

I think I'm missing something in the Search code.

//UPDATE: All of the code.// This is my Insert and Search code:

```
namespace UDDKT
{
    public partial class FrmGlavna : Form
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter DaDavaoci = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlDataAdapter DaAkcije = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\UDDKT.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

        public FrmGlavna()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Popunjava DataGridViews sa podacima iz baze
        private void FrmGlavna_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand SlctDavaoci = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Davaoci ORDER BY DavaocID DESC", cs);
            DaDavaoci.SelectCommand = SlctDavaoci;
            DaDavaoci.Fill(ds, "TblDavaoci");

            SqlCommand SlctAkcije = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM AkcijaDDK", cs);
            DaAkcije.SelectCommand = SlctAkcije;
            DaAkcije.Fill(ds, "TblAkcije");

            DgDavaoci.DataSource = ds.Tables["TblDavaoci"];
        }

        //Povezuje DataGridViews Davaoca i Akcija
        private void DgDavaoci_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ds.Tables["TblAkcije"].DefaultView.RowFilter = "DavaocID =" + DgDavaoci.CurrentRow.Cells["DavaocID"].Value;
            DgAkcije.DataSource = ds.Tables["TblAkcije"];
        }

        //Osvježava DataGridView nakon unosa/izmjene/brisanja podataka u bazu
        private void RefreshTable()
        {
            SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\UDDKT.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            String query = "SELECT * FROM Davaoci ORDER BY DavaocID DESC";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cs);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            DgDavaoci.DataSource = dt;
        }

        //Čisti TextBox nakon upisa/izmjene/brisanja podataka u bazu
        public void ClearTxtBx()
        {
            TxtIme.Clear();
            TxtPrezime.Clear();
            TxtTezina.Clear();
            TxtAdresa.Clear();
            TxtBrojTel.Clear();
            TxtBrojLK.Clear();
        }

        //Upis podataka u Tabelu Davaoci
        private void BtnDodajDavaoca_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String query = "INSERT INTO Davaoci (Ime,Prezime,Pol,DatumRodjenja,KrvnaGrupa,Tezina,Adresa,BrojTel,BrojLK) VALUES (@Ime, @Prezime, @Pol, @DatumRodjenja, @KrvnaGrupa, @Tezina, @Adresa, @BrojTel, @BrojLK)";
            using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\UDDKT.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, cs))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@Ime", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtIme.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Prezime", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtPrezime.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Pol", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = TxtPol.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@DatumRodjenja", SqlDbType.Date).Value = TxtDatumRodjenja.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@KrvnaGrupa", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TxtKrvnaGrupa.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Tezina", SqlDbType.Float).Value = TxtTezina.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Adresa", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtAdresa.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@BrojTel", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtBrojTel.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@BrojLK", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtBrojLK.Text;

                cs.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cs.Close();

                RefreshTable();
                ClearTxtBx();
            }
        }

        //Pretraga postojećih Davalaca
        private void TxtIme_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (DgDavaoci.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Ime LIKE '{0}%'", TxtIme.Text);
        }
    }
}
        }
```

Here is the MockUp of the Form before I begin to type/search/insert Data that isn't already in the Table (First Textbox*).

[image: before]

And after I start typing Name(Име) that starts with an "A" (name that isn't already in the Table).

[image: after]

I want to Search DB for that Column, but if there aren't any existing names, I want to be able to continue typing (without interuption) so that I can Insert new data into table.

Comment: It would come in handy to show us the select code also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DgDavaoci.CurrentRow` in your `DgDavaoci_SelectionChanged` method is null, so attempting to access `DgDavaoci.CurrentRow.Cells["DavaocID"]` throws the `NullReferenceException`. The reason, best I can tell, is as follows:

You begin to type a value into your text box, a value that happens not to be found in the data set. As you type, you cause the `TxtIme_TextChanged` method to execute. It filters according to your search, and since the value is not found, it filters out *every* row in the set. **Here's the important part:** whenever the data set is filtered, it has the possibility of causing `DgDavaoci_SelectionChanged` to execute. Since the selection changed from the first row to no row at all (since there are no filtered rows to display), this method does execute. Now, when the method attempts to access the current row, ***there is no current row***, and so we get a null here. Attempting to access a field of null throws the exception you're getting.

How can you fix this behavior? A simple null-check in `DgDavaoci_SelectionChanged` should do the trick. It looks to me like you can simply return from that method `if(DgDavaoci.CurrentRow == null)`, or you can code in additional behavior. Just perform a check so that you don't reference the null object.

Comment: Yup, that solved the problem. Thanks @params

```
//Povezuje DataGridViews Davaoca i Akcija
        private void DgDavaoci_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DgDavaoci.CurrentRow != null)
            {
                ds.Tables["TblAkcije"].DefaultView.RowFilter = "DavaocID =" + DgDavaoci.CurrentRow.Cells["DavaocID"].Value;
                DgAkcije.DataSource = ds.Tables["TblAkcije"];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the filter inside `TxtIme_TextChanged` is causing the `DataGridView`'s `SelectionChanged` event to fire and the code is entering `DgDavaoci_SelectionChanged`. The exception indicates that `DgDavaoci.CurrentRow` is null, so you'll need to handle the case where `DgDavaoci.CurrentRow` is null in `DgDavaoci_SelectionChanged`.

A simple way to deal with this would be to just check `DgDavaoci.CurrentRow is null` and return from the function if that evaluates to true.

```
private void DgDavaoci_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DgDavaoci.CurrentRow is null)
    {
        return;
    }
    ds.Tables["TblAkcije"].DefaultView.RowFilter = "DavaocID =" + 
        DgDavaoci.CurrentRow.Cells["DavaocID"].Value;
    DgAkcije.DataSource = ds.Tables["TblAkcije"];
}
```

It looks like you might have a second `DataGridView` (`DgAkcije`) that is designed to show the details of the currently selected row in `DgDavaoci`. So, another approach might be to just clear `DgAkcije` if `DgDavaoci.CurrentRow is null`.

```
private void DgDavaoci_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DgDavaoci.CurrentRow is null)
    {
        DgAkcije.DataSource = null; //I'm not 100% sure this will work, I haven't tested it.
        return;
    }
    ds.Tables["TblAkcije"].DefaultView.RowFilter = "DavaocID =" + 
        DgDavaoci.CurrentRow.Cells["DavaocID"].Value;
    DgAkcije.DataSource = ds.Tables["TblAkcije"];
}
```

Ultimately, however, you'll have to decide what you want to happen when `DgDavaoci_SelectionChanged` is called but `DgDavaoci.CurrentRow` is null.

Comment: As I'm still learning will you be able to show me how, please?

Comment: Thank you. It helped to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution if anyone else is interested:

```
 //Povezuje DataGridViews Davaoca i Akcija
        private void DgDavaoci_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DgDavaoci.CurrentRow != null)
            {
                ds.Tables["TblAkcije"].DefaultView.RowFilter = "DavaocID =" + DgDavaoci.CurrentRow.Cells["DavaocID"].Value;
                DgAkcije.DataSource = ds.Tables["TblAkcije"];
            }
        }
```